# Locking down firmware to keep stolen laptop from being formatted?

Tags: command-line, security, terminal, format, firmware

On the Mac laptops there are ways through the terminal to lock down the computer so that if someone tries to format the computer they won't be able to do it without the password. This way locks down the firmware.

Is there a universal way to do the same thing on a PC? I know there are brands out there such as Samsung, Dell, etc that utilize different fimware types, and in turn will mean that their firmware will be locked down differently.

That being said is there a "command code" that will allow you to lock the firmware to keep theives from formatting the hard drive and wiping out your data?

I know a person who has time, and knowledge can get any password, and hopefully the person is smart enough to use another password to lock down the firmware, but that's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking if it's possible, and if so how?

Does the standard PC user require a 3rd party app, or can it be done through the command line? Or Terminal if you are on Linux?

Comment: I am not aware of any feature within any distro of Linux and/or Windows that would allow this to happen.  Furthermore this is easy to get around, take the hdd out of the computer, and hook it up to another one.  This is because of Apple's security hardware on their equipment, which is the only reason, OS X can't run on a Dell.

Comment: There is more than one way to bypass this type of concept, I agree, but what you are looking at talking about is someone above the basic user anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set hardrive / bios passwords in the bios. Usually aceess with one of | del | f1 | f10 | esc | during boot.

NOTE: Any of these can be reset by a person who knows how and has the correct tools. This is true for your mac too, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Obviously about the password if it's known, but I'm talking about the chance of someone who just steals it and knows you from the hole in the wall.  This though is what I was expecting, but I just needed verification.